# Flow typing redux actions - performance issue

Tags: redux, flowtype

I followed flow docs and typed redux action creators using union (https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-actions)

so I have a file with ALL the actions gathered into 1 union like in example:

```
type Action =
  | { type: "FOO", foo: number }
  | { type: "BAR", bar: boolean }
  | { type: "BAZ", baz: string };
```

`Action` type is imported in my reducers and used as in exxample from docs:

```
function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FOO": return { ...state, value: action.foo };
    case "BAR": return { ...state, value: action.bar };
    default:
      (action: empty);
      return state;
  }
}
```

**The problem:**

As I mentioned I gathered ALL the actions in one file - currently ~600 actions in one union. I noticed that lately flow server takes crazy time to start (100+ seconds), rechecking flow is also a pain if change is related to reducer. According to flow logs, files that contain reducers are marked as "Slow MERGE" - 15 to 45s.

After experimenting, I noticed that changing my `Action` type to `any` cuts the time from 100s to 9s.

**The question:**

- can this be related to huge `Action` union?
- should I split it into a few smaller types which will contain only actions to import in particular reducer or this is a wrong way to fix my issue?

Comment: The second option will definitely help "should I split it into a few smaller types which will contain only actions to import in particular reducer or this is a wrong way to fix my issue?" - Yes Also, why are you using 'type' instead of a regular const.  That might be slowing it down too. " Flow can check the code for type errors without having to explicitly annotate that code with types."

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more likely that this one action type is used across your entire app. Any time you make a change to it, Flow needs to recheck a very large number of files. One way to help mitigate this is to ensure all your union actions are in files of their own that don't import other files. Flow can get slow if it has "cycles". One type imports another time which then imports the first time. This can happen if, for example, you define your reducer actions in the reducers themselves. This causes a cycle. Instead, move your action types to their own file.

Additionally, you can use `flow cycle` to output a dot file you can then visualize this file in something like Gephi https://gephi.org/ to detect cycles.